# Register a receiver through xml or call static method when work need to be done off service

Tags: android

I have a service that gets start when push notifications are received. Based on a certain push notification, I would like to do bluetooth work  (discovery and other things). So once the Service receive push notification, I have 2 possible solution ( given the app is not opened):

1-  Call static method that will start doing the work

2- Send a broadcast. On the other hand , I will have the receiver registered through xml (so it can always receives broadcasts).

Which way should I do and why ?
Thank you

Comment: use second one...Because static methods stores in heap and doesn't guarantee to garbage..While broadcast receiver is well documented and garbage collected.

Comment: great point :) thank you.. you may want to put it as an answer

Comment: Or I can start another service and do the work there (and even register the broadcast receivers there if needed, right)?

Comment: It's depends on your need or resources....Services are meant to perform an action in the background for some period of time, regardless of what the user is doing in foreground. on other hand Broadcast receivers are meant to respond to an intent do something, and be done. Well you want to start some bluetooth service for for discovery so you should use service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use Broadcast Receiver not any static methods ...Because static methods stores in heap and doesn't guarantee to garbage..While broadcast receiver is well documented with android system and also garbage collected.